# How to design Business Process Layer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, business-logic

Well, I have some business process such as, creating Appointment List(non-persisted, will be persist later) based on some Configuration. I've service layer, which is transactional, but for reason, I don't need transaction for this task. Where should I place my code? How I separate my business service code from transactional service(working with Dao)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct answer to this.

If you put all this code into your DAO, the DAOs will become huge.

If you put code like this into factories, you will get many, many factories and code working with this type of object will be in several places and developers will spend more time searching for something.

In both cases, you risk code duplication because someone will eventually need functionality that is already there but it's lost in the man methods of the DAO or the many factories/helper classes.